# Запятые перед предлогами "с" и "для"

Tags: пунктуация

В следующих предложениях лишние же запятые?.. Как грамотно объяснить?..

1. Краны оснащены гидравлическим приводом одностороннего действия (,) с возможностью дистанционного управления под водой и обеспечением нормально-закрытого положения запорного органа.
2. Для управления шиберной задвижкой применяется ручной привод с интерфейсом ТНПА (,) для обеспечения возможности закрытия-открытия при помощи глубоководного аппарата.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, надо иметь **свободное мышление,** а у нас еще очень мало этой свободы (почему – это вопрос для психологов).

1. **Нужны ли запятые?** Разумеется, нужны, без них это громоздкое предложение сложно прочитать и понять.
2. **Как грамотно объяснить?** И это не проблема. Обособленные падежные формы являются дополнительной информацией о назначении и характеристиках используемой техники. С точки зрения грамматики это **присоединительные** конструкции.
3. Их можно обособить тире, но и запятых здесь будет **вполне достаточно.**

Answer (score 0):

Оба раза - запятые не нужны. 
Просто нет причин их ставить даже как интонационные, ибо текст технический. 
Хотя, думаю, и в художественном тексте мотивы трудно найти.

Comment: Есть ли какая-то аргументация?.. Во втором случае мне и самой понятно: **привод с интерфейсом для** - единая конструкция... Но в первом возможна другая пунктуация?..

Comment: И как объяснить отсутствие запятой?.. Почему здесь не ставится запятая перед _с возможностью_? Это же определение? Но при этом это нельзя рассматривать как уточнение?

Comment: @Alenka аргументация нужна для постановки знаков, для их отсутствия самая лучшая аргументация - отсутствие мотивов.

Comment: *Это же определение?* -  Разве? Определение чего?  *Но при этом это нельзя рассматривать как уточнение?* - тот же вопрос. Уточнение чего?

Comment: Alenka Два предлога ДЛЯ в одной единой конструкции многовато. Привод — обеспечивающий.

Comment: Мне бы нужно было объяснение - какая часть предложения здесь _с возможностью дистанционного управления под водой_ и как она соотносится с приводом, чтобы понять, почему здесь нету запятой...

Comment: @shampar - но тогда и грамматика поменяется, вопрос уже о другом стоять будет. А это, видимо, не входит в сферу интересов автора.

Comment: Я думала, что это несогласованное определение привода... Привод какой? С возможностью дистанционного управления под водой... уточнение - если эти возможности - дополнительная информация в скобках...

Comment: _Для_ многовато... вижу...

Comment: Ну я бы счел что в конструкции "привод с возможностью" возможность - дополнение. Грамматически по крайней мере.

Comment: Вот... уже спасибо...

Comment: Понимаете, тут грамматика не совсем прозрачная, можно считать, что это "краны с возможность" или "привод с возможностью" (каковая двусмысленность, кстати, не делает чести автору), но вот определения как-то увидел... А вы считаете эту "возможность" **свойством** привода (привод - какой? - с возможностью), так?  Тогда я с вами соглашусь. Но тогда и грамматику надо переосмысливать. И да, тогда мотивы для запятой появляются. Но еще надо думать.

Comment: Ну да, я думаю, что речь именно про привод, раз он в предложении в принципе упоминается.... и после кранов... управляют-то приводом... Но запятой, мне кажется, все равно не нужно...